# Error in Spark task with Kafka and .NET core

Tags: apache-spark, .net-core, apache-kafka

I am trying to read data from Kafka in Spark using .Net Core 3.1. I get NullPointerException and cannot find a reason for it. Maybe someone has encountered this error and found a solution?

- Reading from file works.
- Also tried to change connection details to an external Kafka broker (with authentication), but still, I am getting the same error.
- Source topic on broker exists.

Exception:

```
WARN KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer: Error in attempt 1 getting Kafka offsets:
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.kafka010.KafkaConfigUpdater.setAuthenticationConfigIfNeeded(KafkaConfigUpdater.scala:60)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.ConsumerStrategy.setAuthenticationConfigIfNeeded(ConsumerStrategy.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.ConsumerStrategy.setAuthenticationConfigIfNeeded$(ConsumerStrategy.scala:60)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.SubscribeStrategy.setAuthenticationConfigIfNeeded(ConsumerStrategy.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.SubscribeStrategy.createConsumer(ConsumerStrategy.scala:106)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.consumer(KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.scala:82)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.$anonfun$partitionsAssignedToConsumer$2(KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.scala:533)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.$anonfun$withRetriesWithoutInterrupt$1(KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.scala:578)
        at ...
```

Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession
        .Builder()
        .AppName("kafka_sample2")
        .GetOrCreate();

    var stream = spark.ReadStream()
        .Format("kafka")
        .Option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "127.0.0.1:9093")
        .Option("subscribe", "spark-input")
        .Option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
        .Option("failOnDataLoss", "false");
  
    var dataFrame = stream.Load();

    dataFrame.WriteStream()
        .Format("console")
        .Start();
        
    spark.Stop();
}
```

Spark version:

```
version 3.1.2

Using Scala version 2.12.10, Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_311
Branch HEAD
Compiled by user centos on 2021-05-24T04:46:13Z
Revision de351e30a90dd988b133b3d00fa6218bfcaba8b8
```

Command line:

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2 --class org.apache.spark.deploy.dotnet.DotnetRunner --master local bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\microsoft-spark-3-1_2.12-2.0.0.jar dotnet bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\SparkTest.dll
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession
        .Builder()
        .AppName("kafka_sample2")
        .GetOrCreate();

    var stream = spark.ReadStream()
        .Format("kafka")
        .Option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "127.0.0.1:9093")
        .Option("subscribe", "spark-input")
        .Option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
        .Option("failOnDataLoss", "false");
  
    var dataFrame = stream.Load();

    var query = dataFrame.WriteStream()
        .Format("console")
        .Start();
    
    query.AwaitTermination(); <---needed to call this method
    spark.Stop();
}
```

Comment: i met the same problem, thank you for your answer! this work for me

Comment: Thanks! I had exactly the same issue with PySpark. Calling `query.awaitTermination()` was missing for me as well.